# approximation of $x^2$ in hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, approximation, approximation-theory, least-squares

> use the least squares to find the best linear approximation to $f(x)=x^2$ on [-1,1]. that is find the line $y=a_0+a_1x$ that minimizes $\int_{-1}^1|f(x)-y(x)|^2$

**solution**
I used the theory of approximation in hilbert spaces:
so the inner product is $\int_{-1}^1f(x)g(x)$. f(x)=1 and f(x)=x ae orthogonal polynomials. hence I can find $a_0 = <1,f>=\int_{-1}^1x^2dx=2/3$

$a_1 = <x,f>=\int_{-1}^1x^3dx=0$

so the best linear approximation is $y=2/3$

but what stopped is that the theorem requires f to belong in a hilbert space. Is the space of continuous functions on the mentioned inner product a hilbert space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: The space of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$ is not a Hilbert space under the inner product $(f,g)=\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$.

However, for any inner product space $X$, and fixed $f \in X$, there is always a minimum of $\|f-m\|$, where $m$ varies over all elements of a finite-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{M}$. That minimum is the unique $m\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $(f-m,m')=0$ for all $m' \in \mathcal{M}$. Indeed, if there is some $m\in\mathcal{M}$ for which $(f-m,m')=0$ for all $m'\in \mathcal{M}$, then $(f-m,m-m')=0$ as well, which gives
$$
         \|f-m'\|^{2}=\|f-m+m-m'\|^{2}=\|f-m\|^{2}+\|m-m'\|^{2}\ge \|f-m\|^{2},
$$
and equality holds iff $m-m'=0$. So $m$ is the unique minimum of $\|f-m'\|$ for $m'\in\mathcal{M}$.

To see that such $m$ exists, let $\{ m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_n\}$ be a basis of $\mathcal{M}$. Apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to obtain an equivalent orthonormal basis $\{ e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n\}$. Then
$$
              m = \sum_{j=1}^{n}(f,e_n)e_n.
$$
It's easy to check that $(f-m,e_j)=0$ for all $j$ and, hence, $(f-m,m')=0$ for all $m'\in\mathcal{M}$.

**Your Example**: The function $y=a_0 x+ b_0$ that you want is the unique solution of
$$
             (f-y,1)=0,\;\;\; (f-y,x)=0, \\
          \int_{-1}^{1}(x^{2}-a_0 x-b_0)dx = 0,\;\;\;
          \int_{-1}^{1}(x^{2}-a_0x -b_0)x dx =0, \\
         \frac{2}{3}-2b_0 = 0,\;\;\;
         -\frac{2}{3}a_0 = 0.
$$
**Answer:** $y= \frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the fact that the dot-product space of continuous functions isn't Hilbert has to do with the phenomenon that you can have a sequence of continuous functions converging to a discontinuous limit. Given that you're trying to approximate a continuous function, you should have no problem here.

Second, in order to use the Hilbert space machinery you need to make sure your vectors are orthogonal and normalized. For $e_0 = c$ (a constant) you'll have

$$\int_{-1}^1 c^2 dx = 2 c^2$$

so your $e_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Similarly if you look for $e_1$ as $a+bx$ then because $e_0$ has to be orthogonal to $e_1$, you immediately see that $a=0$, and you have to use $e_1=bx$. Integration gives

$$\int_{-1}^1 b^2 x^2 dx = \frac{2}{3} b^2$$

therefore $e_1 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x$. You can continue [orthogonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) and obtain a quadratic, cubic etc. terms. However if you decided to project your function $f=x^2$ onto a $2$-d subspace spanned by $e_0$ and $e_1$, you will indeed fund that because $x^2$ is orthogonal to $e_1$ you only have a constant term.